# polynomial making with some features

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I need to find polynomial f(x) of degree 1000000, with integer coefficients such that:
1. It evaluates to an integer number in [0, 9] for all integers in [0, 1000000].
2. $f(x) \equiv f(1) \textrm{mod}\ (x - 1)^ 2$
Please note that is naturally satisfied that 
$f(x) \equiv f(1) \textrm{mod}\ x - 1$ because
$f(x) = (x - 1)Q(x) + f(1)$
where Q(x) is the quotient of dividing f(x) to (x - 1);
But we need something stronger here and it should satisfy the condition
$f(x) \equiv f(1) \textrm{mod}\ (x - 1)^ 2$
Such a polynomial was a building block of a midterm exam question that assumed such f(x) exists and asked for something else. My curiosity brought me here to ask about the way to build such a polynomial.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Why is the example you've presented not valid for condition $2$?

Comment: Actually I didn't give the full proof! I solved it for the subproblem consisting of only condition 1.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note your example of $f(x) = (x)(x - 1)...(x - 1000000)$ has $1000001$ factors. It is therefore of degree $1000001$, not $1000000$.

Comment: Thank you very much and nice point pointed out. I'm going to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

$(1-x)(1-\frac {x}{2})(1-\frac {x}{3})\cdots (1-\frac{x}{1000000})$

Equals 0 for all integers in $[1,1000000]$ and equals 1 at $x= 0$

Comment: Nice work, but not the answer I need. Your answer has two problems: coefficients are not integer and also not satisfying the condition two, Because it should have a double factor of 1 as you chose it to evaluate to 0 in point 1, but it just has a single factor of 1.

Comment: Multiplying by $1000000!$ solves the first problem

Comment: Then it creates another problem as it evaluates to 1000000! at 0.